# How can I override content category view to display subcategories as list items

Tags: overrides, templates, subcategories

I'd like to override the category view to display subcategories as list items, my template uses bootstrap and I'd like to get a display similar to thumbnails: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails

Any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own layout file in /templates/your_template/html/com_content/category/default.php and show everything as you wish there. Or you can just override the part for the subcategories which should be the `default_children.php` file.
That is assuming you want to override the default layout. If you want to override the blog one, change `default` to `blog.

Answer (score 0):

From docs.joomla.org:

## 3 Component Output Types and Layout Overrides

### 3.1 Output Types

### 3.2 Layouts

### 3.3 Copying or Creating Layout Files

### 3.4 Overriding Sub-Layouts

http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides#Copying_or_Creating_Layout_Files